# Tensorflow CNN MaxPooling1D is incompatible with the layer error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 2D signal data that is shaped as follows: `(number of signal combinations x number of signals x number of signal points x channel)`, so more clearly, it is: `(10000 x 2 x 51 x 1)`.
I treat my data as an image (basically, its height is 2, its width is 51), and I process it through the CNN architecture as follows:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[3]))
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 3))(input_layer)
x = PReLU()(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units=256)(x)
x = PReLU()(x)
output_layer = Dense(units=1, activation='linear')(x)
```

However, I got error from first maxpooling layer:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 1, 49, 32)
```

After first 2D Conv operation data size becomes `(1, 49, 32)` which is height is 1 and width is 49 so already a 1D data. I guess I do something wrong with the data shape representation but don't know where / how. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: If I apply MaxPooling2D then I got this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "max_pooling2d" (type MaxPooling2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,49,32].
```

Comment: No, its not 1D data,  you need to use MaxPooling2D, isn't it obvious since you are using 2D convolution?

Comment: Additionally, do not forget that convolution and max-pooling input/outputs in 2D should have shape (samples, width, height, channels), you have an image with a width of 1, so applying max-pooling does not make much sense.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you for your answer. Shape of the original dataset is (2 x 51 x 1) which is 2D, and, after applying 2D Conv with no padding it becomes (1 x 49 x 1) which is 1D (I assume?). Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes that is completely wrong. The ND means the number of spatial dimensions, which has not changed in your case.

Comment: I see. So the best way I think is utilizing Conv2D layers like kernel_size=(1, 3), and so on.